# PhantomJs wait for ajax Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phantomjs

estou aqui com um dificuldade imensa em PhantomJS;
Vamos lá desde ontem estou tentando automatizar o processo do denatran dentro de um sistema. Como isso irá funcionar? Eu já tenho o CPF e RENAVAN do usuário, eu tenho um script feito com uma API que resolve o captcha.

Vamos ao problema, eu tenho que ao executar o script colocar os dados do usuário, após isso resolver o captcha que irá retornar os dados json (arquivo php) e depois colocar esse retorno no input e submeter o formulário.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var url = 'http://denatran.serpro.gov.br/certificado/veiculo.asp';

page.open(url, function (status) {
    page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', function () {
        page.onLoadFinished = function () {
            page.render("after_submit.png");
        };

        page.evaluate(function () {
            var image = $('#img_captcha_serpro_gov_br').attr('src');
            $("#txtCodRenavam").val('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
            $("#txtCPFCNPJ").val('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
            $.ajax({
                async: false, // this  
                cache: false,
                url: 'getCaptcha.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {image: image},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br').val(data['captcha']);

                }
            });

        });

        page.render("before_submit.png");
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```